# Cannot move out of borrowed content while creating a mutable iterator over a linked list

Tags: rust

In the book [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/second-iter-mut.html):

```
impl<'a, T> Iterator for IterMut<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a mut T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.next.map(|node| {
            self.next = node.next.as_mut().map(|node| &mut **node);
            &mut node.elem
        })
    }
}
```

```
src/second.rs:104:9: 104:13 error: cannot move out of borrowed content
src/second.rs:104         self.next.map(|node| {
                          ^~~~
```

I cannot understand why `take()` must be invoked before `map()`. The `self.next` is moved out for mutation, and `take()` also moves, correct?

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading the article, I think I get the answer:

`self.next.map` would move the `self.next` as value (into the function you provided to `map`). But the `self` is borrowed as mutable. So `self.next` could not be moved out of borrowed `self`. The way to solve it is to `take()` the ownership of `self.next` first. Correct?

Comment: Not quite, `take()` does not take ownership of `self.next`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at the description of `take`:

> ```
> fn take(&mut self) -> Option<T>
> ```
>
> Takes the value out of the option, leaving a None in its place.

So, `take` does not take ownership of `self.next` (impossible because `self` is only borrowed), but instead takes ownership of the content of `self.next`, replacing it with valid content.

Note that this can be accomplished generically using the `std::mem::replace` function, which accepts any type; `take` is just sugar for `Option`.